# Limit the number of records Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to limit the number of records we receive in a Kafka 0.9.0 consumer ?

Comment: Are you wanting to limit the number of records in batching sense? Like limiting the consumer to only get 10 messages at a time? Or in terms of speed of consuming? Like only getting 100 msg/min?

Comment: "Like limiting the consumer to only get 10 messages at a time" - This is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

The configuration you are looking for is:

```
max.poll.records
```

This set The maximum number of records returned in a single call to `poll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [Broker Configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs). There seems to only be configuration options for controlling records based on bytes.

```
replica.fetch.max.bytes
replica.fetch.min.bytes
```

And all the other configuration options related to messages all seem to be expressed in bytes as well. I believe one of the reasons it was designed this way was to provide a more uniform control of message consumption. Bytes are a very specific way to measure messages. Since messages have the ability to vary widely in number of bytes, attempting to measure in number of messages would give somewhat inconsistent behaviors.

Example. If you had 10 messages of 100 bytes each, the total size would be 1,000 bytes. If you had a second set of 10 messages of 100,000 bytes each. The total size would be 1,000,000 bytes (1MB).

Configuring Kafka in terms of number of messages would treat both these cases exactly the same. But since the size is so different they probably shouldn't be treated exactly the same.

Comment: I had thought about this option but my message sizes vary as you mentioned, so does not serve my purpose here

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying? I was making the case that you should base stuff on bytes rather than number of messages. Do you agree with that or are you still wanting to base things on number of messages?

Comment: What I'm saying is that my message size widely vary and it is hard to limit number of messages I receive in the consumer based on number of bytes in the broker configs

Comment: I would agree with you. Kafka doesn't seem to provide an option for what you're looking for. So I don't know if it's possible to implement your use case.

Comment: What was the reason for limiting the number of records? If it was that you didn't wanted to consume much memory at a time than replica.fetch.max.bytes is the correct option.